# mariadb error loading libsystemd-daemon on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: mariadb

we are running mysql on Ubuntu 20.4
while running mysqld
getting below error
error loading libsystemd-daemon on Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: mariadb-10.3.11/bin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-daemon.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit? MariaDB 10.3.11 was released in 2018 and the missing file issue being reported was primarily seen on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04. So, with this in mind: (1) is this a *new* 20.04 installation or one that has been used for some time? (2) was this 20.04 installation upgraded from 16.04 or older?

Comment: First there is no Ubuntu 20.4. Second Please do not add info for the question to comments. Use edit and add it to the question.

Comment: Thanks matigo
This is new installation and not upgrade 
It’s new Ubuntu 20.04 will this package or library available or we suspect old MySQL version not supported

Comment: David it is 20.04